# Removing parts of a grid in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry to be brief but I have appended these to a grid:

```
$('#grid .box:eq(2)').append('<h1>P</h1>');
    $('#grid .box:eq(27)').append('<h1>P</h1>');
    $('#grid .box:eq(36)').append('<h1>B</h1>');
    $('#grid .box:eq(64)').append('<h1>P</h1>');
    $('#grid .box:eq(69)').append('<h1>P</h1>');
```

If I wanted to remove one of these in an `If` statement, how would I do it?

Comment: `if (1==0) { ...this won't execute ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on some factors. How many of these are added? Are other items appended which are also `h1` elements? Do the box orders vary? It is hard to know for certain without those questions being answered.

Specifically though, if you wanted to remove one of these right after appending, you could use

```
$('#grid .box:eq(64)').find('h1:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some identifier at your appended elements like:

```
$('#grid .box:eq(27)').append('<h1 id="SOMEID" class="OR-CLASS">P</h1>');
```

than check it like:

```
if(CONDITION)
$('#grid .box:eq(27)').find('h1#SOMEID.OR-CLASS').remove();
```

Comment: `addHtml();if(!htmlLooksGood()) removeHtml();` or `while(!htmlLooksGood()){...`